# using $http in angularJS client to call a service running on a remote machine

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have two applications running on my machine:

1) An AngularJS client with ruby as a backend sever on port 3000

2)Another NodeJS app  server on port 4000.

When I try to call the services running on port 4000 from my angularJS client, I see a `200 OK` response but I do not see any data being returned.

ex: from my angularJS, controller file,

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://1.*.*.*:4000/'
}).success(function (data) $scope.test1 = angular.copy(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I get
`{{test1}}` returned.

3) When I make a call to this http://1.*.*.*:4000/ from the browser, I can see the required output.

I am pretty new to Angular and node, I am not sure if I am doing this right?

Comment: Using developer tools, do you see the GET request and the data returned as you expected?

Comment: also check if you are getting any errors. could be a case where .stringify(data) could be causing a issue.

Comment: I removed the stringify part, still no data, From firebug, I see a 200OK response marked in red , with only header and nothing under the response. I changed the code as follows:$scope.test1 = $http.get('http://1.*.*.*:4000/')
                .then(function(response){
                $scope.test1 = response.data;
});
 Now in the output I see "{}". But still no data.If I do a GET directly to http://1.*.*.*:4000/, I get the output, doesnt work when I am calling through a angular client.